# Construct function with Fourier transform compactly supported in interval $[-k,k]$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to construct a function $f$ such that $\hat{f}$ is supported in $[-k,k]$.

My first attempt was to consider the function $$g(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp\left( \frac{k}{k-x^2} \right), & -k \leq x \leq k, \\
0, & \left| x \right| > k. 
\end{cases}$$

The integral of $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$ does not converge however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take \begin{equation} g(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp\left( \frac{1}{x^2-k} \right), & -k \leq x \leq k, \\
0, & \left| x \right| > k. 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This function is in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and so its inverse Fourier decays rapidly.